# Firebase database indexes for many fields that I could query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firebase (cloud firestore) with fields such as: status, role, country, createdAt. I want to query this collection based in any number of fields and combinations of fields.

Now do I really have to create an index for every combination I could query? Assuming I dont use a search service such as Algolia.

e.g:

```
country Ascending role Ascending createdAt Descending
role Ascending country Ascending createdAt Descending
status Ascending country Ascending role Ascending createdAt Descending
etc.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to create an index for every combination of fields that would support a query with a range filter on one of those fields.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation on index types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview):

> Cloud Firestore does not automatically create composite indexes like it does for single-field indexes because of the large number of possible field combinations. Instead, Cloud Firestore helps you identify and create required composite indexes as you build your app.